# how to stop a function call from "resetting" other elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, setinterval

I'm trying to figure out why some of my elements are being reset when functions are called. I don't think the page is refreshed when they are called, so my question is how do I stop this from happening? Or may I have some links to learn about this issue? I'm not too familiar with the terminology so searching hasn't been too helpful

One example element that is being reset is my checkbox (which is connected to line-through styling, which is also reset) and this happens every time the clock on my site refreshes with an updated time through setInterval. It also resets whenever I add a new list element to my site. I hope my question makes sense, thanks in advance!
Here's some of my code if it's relevant:

```
  const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  const [time, setTime] = useState(currentTime);

  function getTime(event) {
    const newTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    setTime(newTime);
  }

  setInterval(getTime, 1000);
```

```
const [isComplete, setIsComplete] = useState(false);

  function strike() {
    setIsComplete(!isComplete);
  }

 <li style={{ textDecorationLine: isComplete && "line-through" }}>
          {props.text}
        </li>
      </div>
      <div className="item-buttons">
        <button onClick={strike}>-</button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            props.onDelete(props.id);
          }}
        >
          x
        </button>
```

Comment: Could you show how the checkbox is linked to the timer ? Otherwise it is difficult to understand what is done wrongly here

Comment: But the ground principle of React is that a whole component is rerendered whenever it's local state is updated. So every variables that are not stored in states will be set with a new initial value every time a state is updated. However, you seems to store those values in states in your example, but maybe the error is present in some parents components I guess ?

Comment: It looks like you're also setting an interval at the top level of your component. This will be called every time your component renders and you'll have more and more intervals. You should set your interval in a `useEffect` with appropriate cleanup.

Comment: @TheTisiboth 
Thanks to you both! It was the parent/top level component and I moved the clock portion of the app to its own component to solve the problem. 
I have another question about creating stable keys, should I make a new thread?

Comment: @pilchard I couldn't tag you in my other reply but thanks!

Comment: @hehe Yes please create a new thread, thank you